# set subreport via code

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have three reports (main.rpt, sub1.rpt, sub2.rpt).
In the main.rpt, in section 2, I have a empty subreport (without connection to the data).

I would decide, via code c#, whether to show sub1.rpt or sub2.rpt inside subreport in section 2 of the main.

I use this to show main report:

```
 r.Load("main.rpt");
 r.SetDataSource(dset);
 crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
 // HOW SHOW sub1.rpt or sub2.rpt in main's section2?
```

Suggestions? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 r.Subreports("Your Sub report").SetDataSource(dset)
```